# I have ERROR with tx in BSC, try to send BEP-20 token

Tags: web3.py

```
def send_tx_to_bsc_addr(tx_amount, tx_bsc_addr):
     bscWeb3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(bscTestnet_url))
     bscContarctABI_USDC = json.loads('[{"inputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"name","type":"string"},{"internalType":"string","name":"symbol","type":"string"},{"internalType":"uint8","name":"decimals","type":"uint8"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"account","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint8","name":"","type":"uint8"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"subtractedValue","type":"uint256"}],"name":"decreaseAllowance","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"spender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"addedValue","type":"uint256"}],"name":"increaseAllowance","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"mint","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"sender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"recipient","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"}]')
     bscContarctAddr_USDC = bscWeb3.toChecksumAddress('0x64544969ed7ebf5f083679233325356ebe738930')
     bscContract_USDC = bscWeb3.eth.contract(address = bscContarctAddr_USDC, abi = bscContarctABI_USDC)
     bscNonce = bscWeb3.eth.getTransactionCount(bscAccount)

     bscTransfer_USDC = bscContract_USDC.functions.transfer(bscWeb3.toChecksumAddress(tx_bsc_addr),
     bscWeb3.toWei(tx_amount, 'wei')).buildTransaction({
       'chainId': 97,
       'from': bscAccount,
       'value': bscWeb3.toWei(tx_amount, 'wei'),
       'gas': 210000,
       'gasPrice': web3.toWei('50', 'gwei'),
       'nonce': bscNonce

     })

     bscSignedTx = bscWeb3.eth.account.signTransaction(bscTransfer_USDC, private_key = PRIVATE_KEY)
     print(bscSignedTx)
     bscTxHash = bscWeb3.eth.sendRawTransaction(bscWeb3.toHex(bscSignedTx.rawTransaction))
```

ERROR: web3.exceptions.ValidationError: Sending non-zero ether to a contract function with payable=False. Please ensure that transaction's value is 0.

IDK whats wrong with code, if someone know where is problem, plz help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to send ETH to a function, the function in the contract must be marked as PAYABLE ("allowed to receive ether")

if the function is not payable, value must be 0
`'value': 0,`

A payable function is something like this:

```
function deposit() payable {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: Could u show me please how to send for example 100 USDC token not 0 USDC, im just beginner in blockchain developing :)

Comment: edited the answer; I suggest to approach solidity with some tutorials like https://cryptozombies.io/